# Run .htaccess rule to remove trailing slash only if such a file exists

Tags: htaccess, redirects, mod-rewrite, trailing-slash

I have the following `.htaccess` rule but I would only like it to run it if a file exists without the removed trailing slash:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

I use LiteSpeed.

Also, what is the difference between the following 2 file checks? And is there any reason that they would both need to be used at the same time for 1 rule? (I currently have a few rules with both).

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Comment: What requests (URLs) you are expecting to be handled by that rule? You wouldn't necessarily expect requests that match the pattern `^(.*)/$` to map to files in the first place, so there may be something else you need to do here (rather than simply slap on a condition that checks whether the request maps to a file). Have you checked the [Apache Docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/) ([mod_rewrite introduction](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html) and [`RewriteCond` reference](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond))?

Comment: "I would only like it to run if a file exists" - Do you understand what that rule is currently doing? What problem is it currently solving?

Comment: It’s removing trailing slashes from everything except directories. (Files and invalid links). I ONLY want it to work for files. (Hence why I'm wanting a file system check to happen first before running the rule.)